# Change the parent of all children

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider the following state in database (MySQL - InnoDB):

`car` table:

[image: cartable]

`wheel` table:

[image: wheel_table]

With the entities:

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    private List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<>();

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Wheel> getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }
}
```

.

```
@Entity
public class Wheel {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public Wheel() {
    }

    public Wheel(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

What I want is to move all `Honda` wheels to `Nissan`. I have tried tons of things, including native queries & `TransactionTemplate`s. However, I was not able to make it work successfully. The main idea of the `@Service` is this (the simplest thing - my first try - the thing I wanted to work):

```
@Service
public class CarService {
    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void transferAllHondaWheelsToNissan() {
        Car nissan = carRepository.findById("Nissan").get();
        Car honda = carRepository.findById("Honda").get();

        List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<>(honda.getWheels());

        wheels.forEach(w -> nissan.getWheels().add(w));

        honda.getWheels().clear();

        carRepository.save(honda);
        carRepository.save(nissan);
    }
}
```

Calling `carService.transferAllHondaWheelsToNissan` does not cause an exception (like I said, I have tried a lot of ways to make it work and many of them were causing exceptions). But, the wheel is deleted and the table is empty. My first thought was that this is caused by the `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)`. Even if I remove it though, the table is still empty and the wheel is gone.

**Is there a way to change the parent of the wheel, having this particular association between the entities?**

Yes, the `@Id` of `Wheel` must be manually assigned. Yes, I would like an undirectional association between those two.

Even If I make it bi-directional, the table gets empty as well:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "car")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<>();
```

In `Wheel` `@Entity`:

```
@ManyToOne
private Car car;
```

`@Service`:

```
@Service
public class CarService {
    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void transferAllHondaWheelsToNissan() {
        Car nissan = carRepository.findById("Nissan").get();
        Car honda = carRepository.findById("Honda").get();

        honda.getWheels().forEach(w -> {
            w.setCar(nissan);
            nissan.getWheels().add(w);
        });
        honda.getWheels().clear();

        carRepository.save(honda);
        carRepository.save(nissan);
    }
}
```

The concept I wanted to follow is.

1. Keep wheels of Honda in a temp variable
2. Clear wheels of Honda
3. `save` (update) Honda (commit transaction???) in order to free primary key values
4. Add wheels to Nissan
5. Store Nissan

So, what am I doing wrong?

I am aware that I can take the `EntityManager` approach without using spring's `@Transactional` but since the relation is `LAZY` I will have to give attention to it too. Plus, in the main application the associations are more "complex" and it will require more effort to do it.

**EDIT:**

`UPDATE wheel SET car_id = 'Nissan' WHERE car_id = 'Honda'` will not work, because Nissan does not (and thats for sure) exist there. Nissan is added during this process too.

Comment: `Nissan is added during this process too` but you are fetching nissan from db in this process so how it is creating? Also `OnDelete` is not needed at all.

Comment: @code_mechanic Yes I know. The edit refers to what happens in the real application. I thought that simplifying it by having it in database would be easier to find & solve the problem. I was probably wrong and should have described exactly the case.

Comment: I don't see any issue in your this must work, we have used bidirectional mapping in our project but it never behaved that way, in your case its not working with bidrectional as well strange!!!, could be because of manual ids??

Comment: I see some issues with your mappings, you have not use `@GeneratedValue` for id fields

Comment: @code_mechanic I do not use `@GeneratedValue` because I do not want the ID to be generated. I manually assign the ID of the entities.

Comment: can you paste the sql statements executed when you run this function?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can use JPA but should remove `orphanRemoval = true` or set `orphanRemoval = false`

btw. your services can improve a bit:

This is redundant

```
    wheels.forEach(wheel -> {
        nissan.getWheels().add(wheel);
    });
```

=>

```
    nissan.setWheels(wheels);
```

Comment: But I need orphan removal for other cases.

Comment: Tel me when you need `orphanRemoval = true` ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your use case and created entities myself and checked, it worked for me fine. I am using hibernate directly but it should not matter. Also used lombok to reduce the boiler plate code.

Here is my code and test case below:

Car entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "car")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class Car {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<Wheel>();

    public void addWheels(List<Wheel> wheels) {
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }
}
```

Wheel entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wheel")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class Wheel {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private Integer carId;
}
```

Test case using hibernate

```
// Provided the Integer ID myself but should work for other type i.e String

@Test
    void shouldTransferHondaWheelsToNissan() {
        doInTransaction(em -> {
            Car car = Car.of(1, "Honda", new ArrayList<Wheel>());

            Wheel wheel1 = Wheel.of(1, 1);
            Wheel wheel2 = Wheel.of(2, 1);

            car.addWheels(Arrays.asList(wheel1, wheel2));

            em.persist(car);
        });

        doInTransaction(em -> {
            Car honda = em.find(Car.class, 1);
            List<Wheel> wheels = honda.getWheels();

            Car nissan = Car.of(2, "Nissan", new ArrayList<>());
            nissan.addWheels(new ArrayList<>(wheels));

            wheels.clear();

            em.persist(nissan);
        });

        doInTransaction(em -> {
            Car nissan = em.find(Car.class, 2);
            Car honda = em.find(Car.class, 1);

            List<Wheel> hondaWheels = honda.getWheels();

            List<Wheel> nissanWheels = nissan.getWheels();

            Assertions.assertEquals(hondaWheels.size(), 0);

            Assertions.assertNotNull(nissanWheels);
            Assertions.assertEquals(nissanWheels.size(), 2);
        });
    }
```

Sql statements executed:

```
 // Create Honda car instance
Hibernate: insert into car (name, id) values (?, ?)

// Adding wheels to honda class
Hibernate: insert into wheel (car_id, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into wheel (car_id, id) values (?, ?)

// when use unidirectional mapping, hibernate creates junction table
Hibernate: insert into car_wheel (Car_id, wheels_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into car_wheel (Car_id, wheels_id) values (?, ?)

// Second transaction - Fetching honda car instance
Hibernate: select car0_.id as id1_0_0_, car0_.name as name2_0_0_ from car car0_ where car0_.id=?

// Fetching wheels for honda car instance
Hibernate: select wheels0_.Car_id as Car_id1_1_0_, wheels0_.wheels_id as wheels_i2_1_0_, wheel1_.id as id1_2_1_, wheel1_.car_id as car_id2_2_1_ from car_wheel wheels0_ inner join wheel wheel1_ on wheels0_.wheels_id=wheel1_.id where wheels0_.Car_id=?

// Creating nissan car instance
Hibernate: insert into car (name, id) values (?, ?)

// Deleting wheels from honda
Hibernate: delete from car_wheel where Car_id=?

// Inserting into wheels of nissan
Hibernate: insert into car_wheel (Car_id, wheels_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into car_wheel (Car_id, wheels_id) values (?, ?)

// Selecting honda instance to verify
Hibernate: select car0_.id as id1_0_0_, car0_.name as name2_0_0_ from car car0_ where car0_.id=?

// Selecting nissan instance to verify
Hibernate: select car0_.id as id1_0_0_, car0_.name as name2_0_0_ from car car0_ where car0_.id=?

// select for wheels
Hibernate: select wheels0_.Car_id as Car_id1_1_0_, wheels0_.wheels_id as wheels_i2_1_0_, wheel1_.id as id1_2_1_, wheel1_.car_id as car_id2_2_1_ from car_wheel wheels0_ inner join wheel wheel1_ on wheels0_.wheels_id=wheel1_.id where wheels0_.Car_id=?

// same here
Hibernate: select wheels0_.Car_id as Car_id1_1_0_, wheels0_.wheels_id as wheels_i2_1_0_, wheel1_.id as id1_2_1_, wheel1_.car_id as car_id2_2_1_ from car_wheel wheels0_ inner join wheel wheel1_ on wheels0_.wheels_id=wheel1_.id where wheels0_.Car_id=?
```

We can clearly see that `orphanRemoval=true` works, as you can see the `delete` statement and then `insert` statement into nissan car.

Database difference in my test is that, I have used `h2` in memory test.

I hope it would help.